# Error:Could not find any matches for com.opentok.android:opentok-accelerator-core:1.0.+

Tags: android, opentok, tokbox

I am integrating video calling functionality in my app using opentok sdk.
I have followed this [this](https://github.com/opentok/one-to-one-sample-apps) and i have successfully integrated.
All were working fine untill today i got this error

```
Error:Could not find any matches for com.opentok.android:opentok-accelerator-core:1.0.+ as no versions of com.opentok.android:opentok-accelerator-core are available.
Required by:
    project :app
```

Can anyone tell me what this error is all about?
 I have tried cleaning,building and Invalid Caches/Restart but nothing works

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a problem with the maven url  'http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven'

Why you don't integrate the module   **Using the repository**

1. Clone the accelerator [core android repository](https://github.com/opentok/accelerator-core-android).
2. Start Android Studio and open your project.
3. From your project, right-click the app name and select New >
   Module > Import Gradle Project.
4. Navigate to the directory in which you cloned OpenTok Accelerator
   Core Android, select accelerator-core, and click Finish.
5. Open the build.gradle file for the app and ensure the following
   lines have been added to the dependencies section:

   compile project(':accelerator-core-android')

**Updated:** Or you can integrate this [jar](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZSdMzUu9pDDvliUUEjJtXKgjYLNAmbwD) (jar of opentok library)

Comment: I have tried that too but still gives the same error for Error:Could not find any matches for com.opentok.android:opentok-solutions-logging:+ as no versions of com.opentok.android:opentok-solutions-logging

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it. I provide you the jar of opentok library. It may help you @AbhayBohra

Comment: This jar does not contains the classes that i have used from accelerator-core